# Locking a user into only accessing four directories

Tags: permissions, directory

I have a situation where I need to allow an outside consultant to access one of our Ubuntu 18.04 systems.
We would like to lock that user's account in a way so that when it logs in, they can only access three or four directories, and only use certain LINUX commands like cd, /bin/cp, more, less, cat, for example.

I know that using sudo, I can configure a list of commands that this user is allowed to use from their $HOME directory. But is there also a way (using sudo) to allow the user to access Directory X but not allow them into Directory Y? For example, the user $HOME is /home/outsider, but I have three folders I want them to also be able to copy files into and read files from:

```
/workdir
/software-repository
/logs
```

I know I can control access to these folders through the group access rights (chmod). But is there a way to NOT allow a specific user access to some directory or file in sudo despite having read access to it on the system?

For example,  /etc/hosts file has the following privileges:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 277 Sep 11 18:09 /etc/hosts
```

So only root can edit this file, but anyone can read it. Is the solution for this example just to chmod 0600 the /etc/hosts? I'm afraid that would cause problems for other apps that may be trying to read the hosts file.

And I can't just chroot the user's account, because they will need to be able to place files in a directory that is outside their $HOME structure.

Right now the only thought is to create a menu that comes up when they log into that account that traps them into a limited number of choices, such as:

```
1) View log file
2) Copy XML template
3) Test print report
0) Log off
```

If anyone has done this before, is there a better way?

Thx,

Steve

Comment: Are you saying that they need access to the *system*? Or that they need access to *data* on that system?

Comment: Other than building a full chroot environment for that user, and chrooting the user, I don't see any other option. Even in chroot, you should be able to provide access to the directories that are outside of `$HOME` by using bind mount for them. Another way is to create a virtual machine to whcih this user will have access and share the needed directories with the host OS.

Comment: Do those directories contain "live" data? Can you `mv` them elsewhere? There's no way to prevent directory traversal "`less ./../../etc/passwd`.

Comment: Is this a hostile access, or a professional co-operative, problem solving visit? Are you paying hourly or by task?

Comment: Hi All,
- They need to be able to log on using sftp to drop off xml files.
- They need to be able to use more or cat to examine logs in two folders
- They need to be able to potentially run a utility to process data and generate a report in PDF format.
- This is a friendly co-op. We just don't want them accessing some other areas of the system that could potentially cause an issue for any other users on the hosted system.

Comment: I think the way to go is what raj suggested. I had planned the chroot'd login originally, but was not thinking of being able to bind mount some of the directories they might need access to. I think I will try something like that and see how well it works.